# Switch to WEBVIEW fails , Appium version 1.4.16.1

Tags: android, appium

I am facing problem in switching to webview. I am using appium version `1.4.16.1`, Android version `6.0.1`, Java `1.8` and API level `23`.

I am using following code to switch for webview

```
driver.getContextHandles();
driver.context("WEBVIEW");
```

Appium log below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but adding this for anyone else with context setting issues. The setter on the context property of the OP is wrong. The log pasted shows the available contexts as NATIVE_APP,WEBVIEW_com.systechone.uniscanbeta. Thus the setter should be:

```
driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.systechone.uniscanbeta");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Android 6 simulator. Check java client's issues
https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/324 , https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6627
The only way is to wait for fix or using older Android version.

Comment: I am facing same problem in android version 5.1.1 also.What could be the solution?

Comment: I've changed my emulator version to `5.1.1` and it worked then. Maybe You can wait a couple of seconds (5 or 6) and then change the context?

Comment: In real device will it work??.since i am supposed to use real device.

Comment: I have put sleep for 1 min den also it is not working.

Comment: In many links they are suggesting to use selendroid mode but selendroid is for android versions lesser than 4.x rite?.can we use selendroid for android versions 5.x and 6.x?

Comment: I've used only emulator, but I'll try to do it on a real device next week. Yes, Seleondroid is used for older devices and I think it won't work on Android > 5.0